# Openvpn tun/tap interface 100% network utilization at idle

Tags: networking, openvpn, wireshark

I have been using my pfsense box as a openvpn server for sometime now with no issues at all, I connect with tun using no compression over UDP using the windows openvpn client. For some reason now when i connect the network utilization on the tun interface shoots up to 100% in task manager and i can confirm lots of data is being sent over the interface by checking the details page, although i have no idea what since I am just sitting on the computer idle. I cannot ping the openvpn server or ping anything else since the interface is being completely flooded. Running wireshark on the tun interface i can see lots of these packets going across, enough to almost make wireshark basically freeze up.

598569  52.156878000    10.0.8.10   OPENVPN_SERVER_IP_CENSORED  OpenVPN 219 MessageType: P_DATA_V1

Does anyone know what the issue might be here?

Edit: Tried reinstalling opevnpn as well, still no luck. Also seems like im not the only person who randomly started having problems with openvpn for what seems like no reason.

Comment: Instead of using Wireshark to capture packets, you could also use `tcpdump`. Use the `-c` parameter to limit the number of packets captured. If you’ve checked that there are no privacy concerns, it would be great if you could provide the capture for us to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your VPN is going *inside itself*. This usually happens if the VPN client sets a default route through the VPN, but forgets to set an exception for the VPN server to use the regular WAN gateway instead.

`route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway` for the client might help with this, although it ought to be automatic.

Comment: I cant even get openvpn to start anymore, the gui log window is blank and then eventually it just says failed to connect. I can still start it from the command line in windows but get a BAD lzo decompression header message, although it shows im connected but I still cannot ping anything. Any Ideas? This problem just popped up out of the blue for what seems like no reason at all.